# How to stop flicker when using jQuery .html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery .html to dynamically change the content of an html div.  When the new content is loaded there is a flicker.  It looks like the flicker is caused by the lower portion of the page rising up to fill in the div I'm updating.  In other words, it looks like the behavior is:

- Set the html of the div to null
- Render the page (thereby causing the flicker)
- Update the html of the div
- Render the page

Is there a way to get rid of the flicker?

The complete code I'm using is shown below (it is available on jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/greshje/pqgjjmL4/2/):

In this example the image of the two mice appears when the page is loaded.  When the "click me" link is pressed the image of the one mouse shows before the other image of the two mice appears.  I would like the image of the one mouse not to move up when the link is clicked.  In the real code I'm developing I don't know the height of the incoming content before it is rendered (it's a data table and the number of rows will vary).

```
<script>
    var isFirst = true;
    var updateImage = function() {
        var html = "";
        var d = new Date();
        if(isFirst == true) {
            html = "<img src='http://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_640x430/public/pinky_primary.jpg?" + d.getTime() + "' />";
            isFirst = false;
        } else {
            html = "<img src='https://www.scrumalliance.org/system/resource_files/0000/0412/pinkyandthebrainwp2.jpg?" + d.getTime() + "' />";
            isFirst = true;
        }
        $("#image1").first().html(html);
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:updateImage();">click me</a>

<div id="image1" align="center">
    <img src="https://www.scrumalliance.org/system/resource_files/0000/0412/pinkyandthebrainwp2.jpg" />
</div>
<br />
<br />

<div id="image2" align="center">
    <img src="http://www.jwwaterhouse.com/pntb/the_brain_t.gif" />
</div>
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: First of all: ID's have to be unique in a document. Then you have two possibilities: Set the container div to a specific height with css and lazy load the images or load both images at page load and just switch them on click

Comment: I changed the name of the second div to "image2".  The images are just an example of the behavior I'm trying to get.  In the real code I'm rendering a table and don't know the height of the rendered content before it is rendered (i.e. the second time I fetch the data, the content could be substantially smaller or larger than the original content).

Answer (score 2):

In general, there are many options to make an update flicker-free.  Two most important things are:

1. The new content should be available when it comes to showing it,
2. Rendering should be partially done by then - as much as possible.

Therefore, I would recommend to load the image in the background, into an image object or a hidden  tag, and only make it visible when it's already loaded.  Here's what I mean:

```
<style>
    .abs {position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;}
</style>
<div style="position:relative">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="pic">
    <img src="2.jpg" class="pic"
        style="visibility:hidden"
        onload="this.style.visibility='visible'"
    >
</div>
```

This solution will load the image and *then* make it visible.  You can use display:none instead of visibility:hidden, but in that case the rendering won't happen until your image is effectively shown.  (Browsers are fast enough to handle this so you'd probably not see a glitch even in this case - but why rely on their speed when you can minimize the time of the problematic phase?)

Also, showing new content first and *then* hiding the old one is often a lot faster, simply because there's less to re-render when you hide something.  The eye considers it faster, too, but that's just an illusion, and in some cases, showing both contents is not an option.

**TLDR: if you want to swap contents fast, make sure the new one is *there already*, just hidden.**

Comment: The images are just an example.  In the real code I'm paging through a very large data table.  The user can select any page to jump to.  Loading every possible page is not an option as it would cause a huge delay on the initial page load.

Comment: Understood but you can still load the new contents (that you would load anyway) before you actually change what's on the screen, and *then* swap visibilities. I know that in some specific cases it's not applicable - but that must be a very rare thing then.  In almost every real-life application, you have the double-display method.

Comment: You mean do something like use a hidden div for the jQuery .html call and then set the content of the visible div to the newly updated hidden div html?

Comment: Either that, or just show the new div instead of the original.  If you have a lot of events bound to the old one, cloning it first to something visible and *then* hiding + updating it is also an option.  Like A is the real table, you copy it to B, show B, hide A, update A, show A, hide B.

Comment: I'm still getting the flickering.  Here's what seems to be happening:  I modify the DOM with the .html call.  I then update the div that shows the data.  However, when the call is made to update the visible div the image download has not completed so I'm still getting the flickering.  Is there a way to essentially say "the DOM has been modified, it's not done updating yet, when it is done run this function"?  Is there a jQuery method that does this ?  Is there a way to invalidate what ever is used to signal $(document).ready so that it will be called when the DOM is done updating?

Comment: Don't modify the visible DOM element. That's what I'm saying. To know when the image has arrived, use the "onload" event of the image. Show only what's complete. Hide what's updating.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `src` of the image, not the entire html of the div:

```
    var isFirst = true;
    var updateImage = function() {
        var src = "";
        var d = new Date();
        if(isFirst == true) {
            src = "http://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_640x430/public/pinky_primary.jpg?" + d.getTime(); 
            isFirst = false;
        } else {
            src = "https://www.scrumalliance.org/system/resource_files/0000/0412/pinkyandthebrainwp2.jpg?" + d.getTime();
            isFirst = true;
        }
        $("#image1 img").prop("src", src);
    }
```

You're also not helping yourself by having two divs with the same ID.  Should be unique.

Comment: I changed the name of the second div to "image2".  The images are just an example of the behavior I'm trying to get.  In the real code I'm rendering a table and don't know the height of the rendered content before it is rendered (i.e. the second time I fetch the data, the content could be substantially smaller or larger than the original content).

Comment: @John - You can't help some flicker if the images are not going to be consistent in size.  That's just the nature of it.

Answer (score 0):

This updates the div using the jQuery .html(html) call and eliminates the flicker (available on jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/evzmjcen/4/).

```
<script>

    var isFirst = true;

    var imageLoaded = function() {
        // set the min height of the visible div to its current height
        $("#image1").css("min-height", $("#image1").height());
        // update the onload (otherwise there's an infinite loop here)
        $("#hiddenImage1").find("img").each(
                function (index, value) {
                    $(value).attr("onload", "");
                }
        );
        // update the visible div
        $("#image1").html($("#hiddenImage1").html());
        // update the height of the visible div to reflect the new size
        $("#image1").css("min-height", 0);
        $("#image1").css("min-height", $("#image1").height());
        // set the hidden div back to empty
        $("#hiddenImage1").html("");
    }

    var updateImage = function() {
        var html = "";
        var d = new Date();
        if(isFirst == true) {
            html = "<img style=\"height:100px;\" onload=\"imageLoaded();\" id='img1' src='http://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_640x430/public/pinky_primary.jpg?" + d.getTime() + "' />";
            isFirst = false;
        } else {
            html = "<img style=\"height:200px;\" onload=\"imageLoaded()\"  id='img2' src='https://www.scrumalliance.org/system/resource_files/0000/0412/pinkyandthebrainwp2.jpg?" + d.getTime() + "' />";
            isFirst = true;
        }
        $("#hiddenImage1").first().html(html);
    }

    var docReady = function() {
    };

    $(document).ready(docReady);

</script>

<a href="javascript:updateImage();">click me</a>

<div id="image1" align="center">
    <img style="height:200px;" src="https://www.scrumalliance.org/system/resource_files/0000/0412/pinkyandthebrainwp2.jpg" />
</div>
<br /><br />

<div id="image2" align="center">
    <img src="http://www.jwwaterhouse.com/pntb/the_brain_t.gif" />
</div>
<br /><br />

<div id="hiddenImage1" align="center" style="visibility:hidden; height:0px;"></div>
<div id="afterHiddenContent">
    This is some content that appears after the hidden div.  
</div>
```

Comment: This version parameterizes the javascript calls and accounts for multiple images in the same div: https://jsfiddle.net/6c1sdo6t/2/